# Trying to save scraped data to an object with nightmarejs, gives me error

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I want to save that data into an json file but first I want to save title,release date, rating and review to movieData Object but it gives me error: movieData is not defined.

```
var Nightmare = require('nightmare');
var fs = require('fs');

var nightmare = Nightmare({ show: true });
var movieData = {};

nightmare
  .goto('http://www.imdb.com/')
  .type('#navbar-query', 'ghostbusters')
  .click('#navbar-submit-button')
  .wait('#main')
  .click('.findSection table .findResult a')
  .wait('#wrapper')
  .evaluate(function () {
    movieData.title = document.querySelector('.title_wrapper h1').innerText;
    movieData.releaseDate = document.querySelector('.subtext a[title*="dates" i]').innerText;
    movieData.rating = document.querySelector('span[itemprop="ratingValue"]').innerText;
    return movieData;
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('Data = ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    return nightmare
      .click('.user-comments .see-more a:nth-child(3)')
      .wait()
      .select('select[name="filter"]', 'chrono')
      .wait('#wrapper')
      .evaluate(function () {
        movieData.review = document.querySelector('#tn15content p').innerText;
        return movieData;
      })
      .end()
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log('Review = ' + data.review);
      })
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });
```

Comment: On which line are you getting the error?

Comment: it doesn't say. all it says is: Search failed: movieData is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is one of scope. 
`movieData` in your second evaluate statement does not work becuase it is in a different scope as compared to the original `movieData` object literal in the first `evaluate` function. 
To pass the scope, you need to make the changes as below.

```
nightmare
  .goto('http://www.imdb.com/')
  .type('#navbar-query', 'ghostbusters')
  .click('#navbar-submit-button')
  .wait('#main')
  .click('.findSection table .findResult a')
  .wait('#wrapper')
  // .evaluate(data1())
  .evaluate(function () {
    var movieData = {}
    movieData.title = document.querySelector('.title_wrapper h1').innerText;
    movieData.releaseDate = document.querySelector('.subtext a[title*="dates" i]').innerText;
    movieData.rating = document.querySelector('span[itemprop="ratingValue"]').innerText;
    return movieData;
  })
  .then(function (data) {
    console.log('Data = ' + JSON.stringify(data));
    return nightmare
      .click('.user-comments .see-more a:nth-child(3)')
      .wait()
      .select('select[name="filter"]', 'chrono')
      .wait('#wrapper')
      .evaluate(function (b) {   
        b.review = document.querySelector('#tn15content p').innerText;
        return b;
      }, data)
      .end()
      .then(function (data) {
        console.log('Review = ' + data.review);
        console.log(data);
      })
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    console.error('Search failed:', error);
  });
```

This works because you are passing your object `movieData` from the first `then()` function to the second `then()` and passing it into the third scope which is `.evaluate()` through `b`.